# What are some strategies to stage commits with TFS?

Tags: tfs, staging

I'm using TFS 2010 as a Source Control System and have the problem that I want to do multiple commits, but cannot check them in because of a policy that requires a review.

I want to do more commits (pretty much every few minutes) than reviews. Basically I want to commit to some temporary place and then when someone reviews the individual commits they get promoted to the main Source Control.

Shelving doesn't solve this properly, because you cannot commit a Shelveset directly. Since it's not a DVCS, I cannot do local commits.

Is my only option to create a private branch and have the reviewer merge it into the trunk?

Or is there a sane alternative for this scenario?

Comment: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2312852-enable-distributed-source-control-dvcs-

Comment: You _can_ commit a shelveset directly in TFS2010, but it requires use of the command line. `tf checkin /shelveset:shelvesetname[;shelvesetowner]` Enter the reviewer, task, and check-in comments when you create the shelveset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A separate branch is what I would recommend.

You'd basically be following a branch by quality pattern.  Unreviewed Code Branch, Reviewed Code Branch.

Comment: In my specific case I've solved this by using Mercurial locally and only committing into TFS rarely. If that's not an option, branching is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It is not helping you right now, but in Dev11 we are shipping the Code Review feature which you can use for these kind of processes. You can see it in the [\BUILD\ presentation of Cameron and Brian](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-833T) and [of Jamie](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-811T).

You can also download a [copy of the Developer Preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/09/14/visual-studio-11-developer-preview-announced.aspx) to play with it yourself